# ASP.Net DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Event fires but does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, dropdown, selectedindexchanged

I have the following `ASP.Net` code:

**code.aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>DropDownList One</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnSelectedIndexChange="ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </td>
            <td>DropDownList Two</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTwo" runat="server" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**code.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       ddlTwo.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlTwo.Visible = true;
}
```

**What I Expect:**

This code is supposed to make `ddlTwo` visible upon `ddlOne`'s selected index changing.

**What Actually Happens:**

Upon changing the index of `ddlOne`, the `ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged` function runs (test with debug) and the `ddlTwo.Visible = true;` runs too but the and the property is changed as I step through the process but the moment the function is over and I want to see my results (i.e. the visible `ddlTwo` control), there's no result.

If anyone can spot the issue, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: have you used script manager?

Comment: Can you give `upMain.Update()` a try? This is assuming the UpdateMode of you Update Panel is conditional.

Comment: @Imad Yes I've used ScriptManager

Comment: @GeraldGonzales I just gave that a shot but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you also debugged through he Page_Load? I have a suspicion that something might be triggering requests to server twice

Comment: @Andrei Yes I've checked that, the `IsPostBack` property is true upon that event firing and there's nothing outside the `if ( !IsPostBack ) {...}` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
OnSelectedIndexChange="ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

to

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlOne" 
    EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

inside update panel.

Comment: I gave this a try and I still get the same undesired result.